# Reduce setTimeout time relative to time left

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a random "spinner" that loops through 8 divs and add a class active like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/9q1tf51g/

```
//create random setTimeout time from 3sec to 5sec
var time = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5000 - 3000 + 1)) + 3000;
var exit = false;

function repeat(){
    //my code
    if(!exit){
        setTimeout(repeat, 50); 
    }
}
```

My problem is, I want the function repeat to end slowly, to create more suspense. I think I can do this by raising the 50 from the timeout but how can I do this accordingly to the time left?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
var time = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5000 - 3000 + 1)) + 3000;
var anCounter = 1;
var anState = "positive";
var exit = false;
//var time1 = 50000;
setInterval(function(){time = time-1000;}, 1000);
function repeat(){
    if(anCounter>7 && anState=="positive"){ anState="negative"}
    if(anCounter<2 && anState=="negative"){ anState="positive"}

    $('div[data-id="'+anCounter+'"]').addClass('active');
    $('div').not('div[data-id="'+anCounter+'"]').removeClass('active');

    if(anState=="positive"){anCounter++;}else{anCounter--;}
    if(!exit){
if(time <1000)
        setTimeout(repeat, 300);
  else if(time< 2000)
  setTimeout(repeat, 100);
  else setTimeout(repeat, 50);

    }
}

repeat();
setTimeout(function(){
exit=true;
},time);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you know that you need to exit the flow (exit is true ) you can trigger some animation by creating a dorm linear serials of you code. Usually this animation should not last more than 2 sec.

Answer (score 0):

## [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/warkentien2/9q1tf51g/10/)

**Linear deceleration:** *//values are just an example:*

1. add a `var slowDown = 0;` inside the click event handler
2. add `slowDown += 1;` inside the `repeat` function
3. pass `50+slowDown` to `setTimeout`

**Curved deceleration:**

1. add a `var slowDown = 1;`
   and a `var curveIndex = 1.05 + Math.random() * (0.2);` *// [1.05-1.25)*
   inside the click event handler
2. add `slowDown *= curveIndex;` inside the `repeat` function
3. pass `50+slowDown` to `setTimeout`

Comment: This works but it tends to fall on the last 2-3 squares all the time, how can I fix this? (using the curve deceleration)

Comment: your `var time = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5000 - 3000 + 1)) + 3000;` only gets values between 3001 and 5001 so it ends up falling mostly where you said. **Fix 1** increase the time window: e.g.: 6000 - 3000 or 6500 - 3000. (note, you could just right the result of this equation..: 3001 instead of 6000-3000+1). **Fix 2** use a random generated curve function `var curveIndex = 1.05 + Math.random() * (0.2);` and `slowDown *= curveIndex;`

Answer (score 0):

You were kind of on the right track but it'd be easier to check the time you've passed by and increment accordingly at a fixed rate.  I set it to increase by `50ms` every iteration but you could change that to whatever you like.

## [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9q1tf51g/6/)

**Javascript**

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var time = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5000 - 3000 + 1)) + 3000;
    var anCounter = 1;
    var anState = "positive";
    var elapsed = 0;
    var timer;

    function repeat(timeAdded) {
        if (anCounter > 7 && anState == "positive") {
            anState = "negative"
        }
        if (anCounter < 2 && anState == "negative") {
            anState = "positive"
        }

        $('div[data-id="' + anCounter + '"]').addClass('active');
        $('div').not('div[data-id="' + anCounter + '"]').removeClass('active');

        if (anState == "positive") {
            anCounter++;
        } else {
            anCounter--;
        }
        if (elapsed < time) {
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                repeat(timeAdded + 50);
            }, timeAdded);
            elapsed += timeAdded;
        }
        else {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }

    repeat(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parameter called `intTime` to your `function repeat` and inside that function you can adjust the next timeout and call the repeat function with the new timeout. each time it gets called it will take 20 ms longer. however you adjust the increment by changing the `20` in
 `var slowDown=20;` to a different number.

```
var slowDown=20;
setTimeout ("repeat",50);

function repeat(intTime){
    //my code
    if(!exit){
        intTime=Math.floor (intTime)+slowDown;
        setTimeout(repeat(intTime), intTime); 
    }
}
```

And then you will need to create another timeout for the exit.

```
var time = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5000 - 3000 + 1)) + 3000;
var exit = false;

setTimeout ("stopSpinning",time);

function stopSpinning(){
   exit = true;
}
```

---

so the whole thing should look something like this

```
var slowDown=20;
var time = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5000 - 3000 + 1)) + 3000;
var exit = false;

setTimeout ("stopSpinning",time);
setTimeout ("repeat",50);

function repeat(intTime){
    //my code
    if(!exit){
        intTime=Math.floor (intTime)+20;
        setTimeout(repeat(intTime), intTime); 
    }
}

function stopSpinning(){
   exit = true;
}
```